# Why does the "welcome" banner on first visit say the site is for game developers?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just came to the site for the first time. The banner across the top said something to the effect of "Welcome to the Q&A site for professional and independent game developers."

Is this a copy & paste oversight from another StackExchange site?

Comment: I actually got "Welcome to Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users", maybe it's trying random taglines?

Comment: I'm getting "peer programmer code reviews", maybe it's fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, this was wrong. Fixing now.