# No rep gain from Meta question: reputation lag or bug?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, specific-question, reputation, meta

I posted [this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/why-does-the-welcome-banner-on-first-visit-say-the-site-is-for-game-developers) an hour ago.

My profile page shows 3 up-votes and accept for 17 rep, but this is not reflected in my total, which is 101.

I'm not concerned with accumulating rep here, but this is contrary to the way I've seen rep applied on other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 8):

Please read the [FAQ](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/FAQ):

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.
>
> (Please note that offensive penalties, if levied by the community through spam or offensive votes on your posts here, will affect your reputation on the main website.)

Comment: That is what I thought, until I went to "Recent Activity," where it shows reputation tallies. Silly.

Comment: Just think of it in terms of upvotes and downvotes.  (: